# Can't flag to close as "Off-topic" with custom reason

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

If I flag a question on SU, I have the three close reasons (product reccomendations, software dev, web apps, the "This question belongs on another site" or "Other (add a comment).

If I flag a question on SF, I have the three close reasons, and "this questions belongs on another site" but no "other - add a comment" dialogue.

This happens in both IE 9 and FF 21. I have 2233 rep on SF and 4616 rep on SU.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[According to Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/189912):

> That was a last-minute bug fix. See, while meta let you enter a custom reason, it didn't actually *do* anything with that reason. This isn't ideal. So it was fixed before the network-wide rollout, and should disappear from Meta as well soon.
>
> Folks who can vote to close directly still have the option, and it creates a comment along with their vote.
>
> We'll revisit the need for a low-rep user "other" option based on usage, but initially we're trying to restrict the use of flag-to-close to problems that are generally agreed-on by the community.
>
> If you see a post that should be closed for an unusual reason, you have the option of flagging for moderator attention, selecting "other" and describing that reason in detail.